# How to bind using docker http API

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, dockerode

***Update***

I Think I need to use the .run instead of .createContainer

I got the command to work without a mount however im not sure how to bind docker container to my cwd

```
    docker.run("wpscanteam/wpscan", [
        // "--mount",
        // "type=bind,source=" + process.cwd() + "/docker-bind,target=/output",
        // "-o",
        // "/output/wpscan-output.json",
        "--format",
        "json",
        "--url",
        "https://example.com/",
    ], process.stdout, function (err, data, container) {
        console.log(data.StatusCode);
    })
```

The commented lines (2-6) cause errors if uncommented `Scan Aborted: invalid option: --mount`

I am allowed to add [these](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ContainerCreate) create arguments and I think I need to use `volume` but I am not sure.

**OG Post**

I am trying to use [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) to execute this docker command `docker run --rm --mount type=bind,source=$HOME/docker-bind,target=/output wpscanteam/wpscan:latest -o /output/wpscan-output.json --format json --url 'https://example.com/'`

Here is what I tried however when I run this makes the container with the proper commands however it (almost) immediately exits and when i `docker container inspect` the contatiner that was created it does not have the mounted volume

i'm not sure `Mount` is the correct argument I should be using but I don't think that is the problem here because the docker instance stops in <.5secs and when I run the command in WSL it takes about  10 seconds to run so I don't think my `cmd:[]` argument is being executed.

```
docker.createContainer({
        Image: 'wpscanteam/wpscan',
        AttachStdin: false,
        AttachStdout: true,
        AttachStderr: true,
            Mounts:
                [
                    {
                        "Type": "bind",
                        "Source": process.cwd() + "/docker-bind",
                        "Destination": "/output",
                    }
                ],
        Tty: false,
        Cmd: [
            "-o",
            "/output/wpscan-output.json",
            "--format",
            "json",
            "--url",
            "https://example.com/"
        ],
        OpenStdin: false,
        StdinOnce: false
    }, (err, container)=>{
        container.start(function (err, data) {
            console.log(data)
            console.log(err)
        })
    })
```

When i run this command `docker run --rm --mount type=bind,source=$HOME/docker-bind,target=/output wpscanteam/wpscan:latest -o /output/wpscan-output.json --format json --url 'https://example.com/'`
in WSL 2 it works perfectly placing the JSON in the docker-bind folder on my disk.

When converting this command to the dockerode I used `process.cwd()` instead of $HOME because $HOME is a WSL feature. (I also do have the `docker-bind` folder in my project directory so that shouldn't be a problem)

I am fairly experienced with docker however this is wayy beyond my expertise.

tl;dr I have a docker command which I need the output to be placed into a folder within my project directory. It needs to be able to be  run using Node.js

If there is a better library that is well supported please let me know.

Docker [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerCreate) for you convenience (1.42)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for the answer

```
docker.run("wpscanteam/wpscan", [
            "-o",
            "/output/wpscan-output.json",
            "--format",
            "json",
            "--url",
            "https://example.com/",
        ], process.stdout, {
        HostConfig:{
            Binds:[
                process.cwd() + "/docker-bind:/output"
            ]
        }
        }, function (err, data, container) {
            console.log(data.StatusCode);
        }
    )
```